# Symfony2 composer installing one new bundle without updating other dependencies

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have a stable project thats been in production for a year now, but the time has come for some upgrades. I want to install a new bundle, but I dont want to update any other packages to their new versions.

When I deploy the project i do `composer.phar install` witch installs the vendors from `composer.lock` file with the right versions. Everything is fine here.

I cant do `composer.phar update` because that will update all of the vendors + it throws hundred dependency errors anyway.

I want to istall just one new vendor.

My composer.json looks like this:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
        "sonata-project/core-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/media-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sparkling/adyen-bundle": "^0.3.4",
        "sylius/translation-bundle": "^0.15.0",
        "sylius/shipping-bundle": "^0.15.0",
        "sylius/resource-bundle": "0.15.*",
        "sylius/payment-bundle": "0.15.*",
        "winzou/state-machine-bundle": "^0.2.2",
        "sylius/currency-bundle": "^0.15.0",
        "sylius/money-bundle": "^0.15.0",
        "ddeboer/data-import-bundle": "dev-master",
        "eko/feedbundle": "1.2.5",
        "ed/blog-bundle": "v1.0.3",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "hwi/oauth-bundle": "^0.3.9",
        "facebook/php-sdk-v4": "^5.1",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^1.6",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.3",
        "oneup/uploader-bundle": "~1.3",
        "suncat/mobile-detect-bundle": "^0.10.2",
        "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "^3.1",
        "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "^1.0",
        "stfalcon/tinymce-bundle": "1.0"
    },
```

The last bundle in the list: `"stfalcon/tinymce-bundle": "1.0"` is the bundle I want to install. I added this by hand.

After adding the bundle I am trying to do:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar update stfalcon/tinymce-bundle --with-dependencies
```

This still throws errors:

```
Domas@Lenovo-PC MINGW64 /c/wamp64/www/karpedeal (develop)
endenciesmemory_limit=-1 composer.phar update stfalcon/tinymce-bundle --with-depe
Warning: This development build of composer is over 60 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package sensio/distribution-bundle == 3.0.31.0 is satisfiable by sensio/distribution-bundle[v3.0.31] but those are rejected by your minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package sonata-project/intl-bundle == 2.2.3.0 is satisfiable by sonata-project/intl-bundle[2.2.3] but those are rejected by your minimum-stability.
  Problem 3
    - The requested package knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle == 2.5.0.0 is satisfiable by knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle[2.5.0] but those are rejected by your minimum-stability.
  Problem 4
    - sonata-project/user-bundle dev-master conflicts with sonata-project/intl-bundle[dev-master].
    - sonata-project/intl-bundle dev-master conflicts with sonata-project/user-bundle[dev-master].
    - sonata-project/intl-bundle dev-master conflicts with sonata-project/user-bundle[dev-master].
    - Installation request for sonata-project/intl-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/intl-bundle[dev-master].
    - Installation request for sonata-project/user-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[dev-master].
```

I dont know what else to do.. Is there a way to install new bundles without having these problems?

Comment: php composer.phar require stfalcon/tinymce-bundle='1.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as removing it from your composer.json and execute :

```
php composer.phar require stfalcon/tinymce-bundle:1.0
```

If you still have any errors, it may be due to the dependencies of this particular bundle conflicting or being incompatible with your own dependencies.

And you should definitely not rely on dev-master version. Use specific versions instead like "^3.10.0" for every requirement to your app. Master branch on a project may not be stable and up-to-date, specifically regarding to the composer.json dependencies declarations. Replacing dev-master by an accurate choice may fix your issues.

Comment: from what I see in your post you're doing an update, not a require, when you get conflicts. Can you post the errors you get from a require ?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler command from your Symfony2 directory is:

```
composer require stfalcon/tinymce-bundle "dev-master"
```

I think it should work, can you try it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a best way to install bundle

I have faced same problem today and i have installed specific bundle using **require** command

like :

```
composer require bundleName version
```